# I have a problem creating admin user orchid, in the command php artisan orchid:admin admin admin@admin.com password

Tags: laravel, orchid

I'm trying to install orchid laravel admin panel but I can't create this admin user, I'm just following the installation in orchid
How could I fix this error?

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\orchid-project> php artisan orchid:admin admin admin@admin.com password could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select exists(select * from `users` where `email` = admin@admin.com) as `exists`)

I already enabled extension=pdo_pgsql in php.ini in xampp, but it doesn't work.

Comment: there is more than one `php.ini` file